# Fourier series in Heisenberg's paper

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-series

I have been studying some articles by W. Heisenberg, and a step appeared that I do not understand. My problem appears in the integration. I don't understand two things in the integration result. Why is omega not squared and why does $a_{-\alpha}(n)$ appear? Does anyone understand? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add some detail regarding where you got stuck or which bit you do not understand

Comment: Now I was more explicit in my doubts. Thank you Oliver

Comment: its a consequence of the [Cauchy product](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_de_Cauchy) of the series $\dot x$ with itself, and the orthogonality of the Hilbert basis $e^{i \alpha  \omega _n t}$